# How to vertically center a text label in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have tried the tkinter module before, but gave up shortly after. I'm trying to learn it now so I'm still a beginner. I'm trying to vertically center a text label, but nothing is working. I've googled this multiple times. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.l1 = tk.Label(self, text="Hover over me")
        self.l1.update()
        self.l1.pack()

        self.l1.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.l1.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.l1.configure(background="blue")

    def on_leave(self, enter):
        self.l1.configure(background="red")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Window(root).pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="true")
    root.geometry('1920x1080')
    root.state('zoomed')
    root.title("Color Switcher ~ Hydra")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mention `expand=True` when you pack the `tk.Label`.

```
class Window( tk .Frame ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs )

        self.l1=tk.Label(self,text='Hover over me')
        self.l1.pack(expand=True)

        self.l1.bind('<Enter>',self .on_enter)
        self.l1.bind('<Leave>',self .on_leave)

    def on_enter(self,event):
        self.l1.configure(background='blue')

    def on_leave(self,enter):
        self.l1.configure(background='red')
```

Comment: On the 5th line you forgot the 't' for 'tk.Label' (it should be  self.l1=tk.Label(self,text='Hover over me')). But other than that, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think `expand=True` is what you're trying to do, so  widgets expand to use that area.  You already did that with your window, but not l1.  Your label won't get bigger though, unless you specify character sizes for it.  So it'll just be floating there, in empty space.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
Width, Height = 1920, 1080

class Window( tk .Frame ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        tk .Frame .__init__( self,  *args,  **kwargs )

        self .l1 = tk .Label( self,  text='Hover over me' )
        ##  self .l1 .update()  not needed
        self .l1 .pack( expand=True )

        self .l1 .bind( '<Enter>',  self .on_enter )
        self .l1 .bind( '<Leave>',  self .on_leave )

    def on_enter( self, event ):
        self .l1 .configure( background='blue' )

    def on_leave( self, enter ):
        self .l1 .configure( background='red' )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk .Tk()
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}' )
    Window( root ) .pack( expand='true' )
    ##  root .state( 'zoomed' )
    ##  _tkinter .TclError: bad argument 'zoomed': must be normal, iconic, or withdrawn
    root .attributes( '-zoomed',  True  )
    root .title( 'Color Switcher ~ Hydra' )
    root .mainloop()
```

Comment: Then I got this error ```tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"```

Comment: How are you calling the script?  `chmod +x vertically_centered.py` then `./vertically_centered.py`